# Changing a class state in a wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins

I've set up a plugin using a class. I also have a class for my ajax hooks. I try to create a GymChain object and it's children which work fine. But only `updateMembershipPricing` does not update the values for an underlaying class MembershipDuration. When testing this with hardcoded values in a template file it does work fine. But not in my ajax class. for the rest all data which is expect is being returned. Is this the right approach to have this kind of behaviour?

```
public static function getMembershipTypeAndDurations(){
        if(!isset($_POST['locationId'])) wp_send_json('');
        
        $locationId = (int) $_POST['locationId'];
        $getMemberships = (new SportivityClient($locationId))->getMemberships();
        $gymChain = self::setupGymChain();
        if($getMemberships['statusCode'] !== 200) wp_send_json('Geen memberships gevonden');
        $sportivityMemberships = $getMemberships['MembershipDefinitions'];
        $gymChain->updateMembershipPricing($locationId, $sportivityMemberships);
        $location = $gymChain->getLocationById($locationId);
        $memberships = $location->getMembershipTypes();
        wp_send_json($memberships);
    }
```

Comment: You might be misunderstanding how PHP works. Dynamic values in a class will not persist across multiple requests (a page visit is one request, an AJAX request is another request). To persist values across requests you need to use cookies or the database. This is just how PHP works and not anything to do with WordPress. So if you want the membership pricing change to persist then your `updateMembershipPricing` method needs to update that pricing in the database. Setting a value on a class will not do anything permanent.

Comment: your class is loaded and created from scratch on every request, and at the end everything is wiped clean. If you want something to persist between requests you have to store it somewhere like a cookie, a file or the database. You can't set a variable in one request then read it in another

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the right approach to have this kind of behaviour?

No, this kind of behaviour requires a persistant running application that stays in memory, like a NodeJS application, *but that's not how PHP works.*

> But only updateMembershipPricing does not update the values for an underlaying class MembershipDuration.

It does! But the important thing to note is that they might be the same code but they are not the same object. **The object/class with the variable that you updated in your AJAX request died the moment the AJAX request ended and no longer exists.**

**Every single HTTP request you make to the server starts with a blank slate, loading WordPress and your plugins/themes fresh.** At the end of the request everything is wiped clean.

So variables you set on one request do not exist on the next request, there is no continuity. Hooks are added every single time you make a request not just when the code first runs, and variables need to be set up on every single request. Likewise PHP files need to be loaded again too.

This means if you want to set a variable in an AJAX request then use it on a page load, your AJAX request has to store that variables value somewhere persistent then your code needs to retrieve it when needed. This could be in the database, a file, cookies, etc.

> When testing this with hardcoded values in a template file it does work fine.

The reason this works is because on every page load it reads in the template file and sees the hardcoded values. These values are persisted in files on the server so they survive the request. Unfortunately because they're hardcoded they can't change, and if they did they'd change for everybody which would be a massive security and performance issue.

#### Where Should I Store Things

- If it's specific to the user: User meta
- If it's specific to this visitor/session: cookies
- If it's specific to a post: a taxonomy if you need to filter/group by it, or post meta for everything else
- If it's specific to a site: options
- If it's specific to a comment: comment meta
- If it's UI state: Store it locally or bundle it into the URL somehow